# what is Alternative of Paint and repaint function?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, awt

Is there any function which can be replaced with `paint()` and `repaint()`in java.

**I have a scenario.**

There is a triangle **(Triangle 1)**. when user will click in triangle another triangle **(Triangle 2)** will appear and 1st **(Triangle 1)** will be removed from screen. (coded using `JFrame`, `paint()` and `repaint()`)

I have achieved it so far. but problem is when I minimize or change size of window with mouse the output window, it just paint again **Triangle 1** rather than **Triangle 2**. **OR** Clear the whole screen if i call  `g2d.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

triangle.reset();`

**Note:** These both functions are to remove previous triangle (Triangle 1).

Is there any function that state should not be changed on minimize or when window size changed ?

or can we override `repaint()` or anything helping according to scenario.

Here is the Working code. Execute it, Click in triangle then minimize and see again. You will get the problem more clearly.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Triangle_shape extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public static JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");

    public Triangle_shape() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new TrianglePanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(btnSubmit, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.repaint();
        frame.setTitle("A Test Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    public static class TrianglePanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

        private Polygon triangle, triangle2;

        public TrianglePanel() {
            //Create triangle
            triangle = new Polygon();
            triangle.addPoint(400, 550);        //left   
            triangle.addPoint(600, 550); //right
            triangle.addPoint(500, 350); //top

            //Add mouse Listener
            addMouseListener(this);

            //Set size to make sure that the whole triangle is shown
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        }

        /**
         * Draws the triangle as this frame's painting
         */
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.draw(triangle);
        }

        //Required methods for MouseListener, though the only one you care about is click
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        /**
         * Called whenever the mouse clicks. Could be replaced with setting the
         * value of a JLabel, etc.
         */
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) this.getGraphics();
            Point p = e.getPoint();
            if (triangle.contains(p)) {
                System.out.println("1");

                g2d.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
                triangle.reset();
                g2d.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                triangle2 = new Polygon();
                triangle2.addPoint(600, 550);  // left
                triangle2.addPoint(700, 350); //top
                triangle2.addPoint(800, 550);  //right
                g2d.draw(triangle2);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Triangle dont have point");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The short answer is NO, and DON'T try.  Work within the API confines are you will have hair.

Comment: Working code is updated please take a look again Thanks

Comment: I can't make head or tail of this. There is no alternative to the `paint()` or `repaint()` methods, and they aren't equivalents or alternatives to each other either.

Answer (score 2):

`paint()` and `repaint()` work fine, but you are not using them as they are designed to be used. The window system doesn't keep a persistent image of what a component looks like. It expects your component to be able to repaint its entire appearance on demand (such as when the window is resized or un-minimized).

If you grab a Graphics object with `getGraphics()` and draw something on the component, the stuff you draw will indeed be lost if/when the entire component needs to be repainted. So you should not do that, but instead make sure your `paintComponent` method has all the information it needs to *completely* repaint the component.

---

If you only want one triangle on the screen at once, do not create a separate variable `triangle2`. Just replace the one triangle you have by altering your mouse click handler as follows:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    Point p = e.getPoint();
    if (triangle.contains(p)) {
        triangle = new Polygon();
        triangle.addPoint(600, 550); // left
        triangle.addPoint(700, 350); //top
        triangle.addPoint(800, 550); //right
        repaint();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Point not in triangle");
    }
}
```

Your `paintComponent` method should call `super.paintComponent` to ensure the background is painted, but otherwise you do not need to change it:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.draw(triangle);
}
```

Alternatively if you are trying to keep multiple triangles on the screen, for example, to add a new one at every click, you should add them into a [list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of shapes which will be drawn whenever the component needs to be repainted:

```
private final List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    for (Shape s : shapes)
        g2d.draw(s);
}
```

Then to control the set of shapes that is on screen, manipulate the contents of the list, and call `repaint();`.

For instance, to add a new shape to the ones on screen:

```
Polygon triangle = new Polygon();
triangle.addPoint(200, 300);
triangle.addPoint(200, 200);
triangle.addPoint(300, 200);
shapes.add(triangle);
repaint();
```

To remove all shapes from the screen:

```
shapes.clear();
repaint();
```

---

You should also make sure that you switch to the Swing thread at the start of the program, because it is not safe to interact with Swing components from the main thread. In `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            .
            .
            .
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { ..` should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g); ..`

Comment: @AndrewThompson It sounds like OP wants to draw the entire appearance of a component, not draw over any default text on it, so it is not useful to not call super.paintComponent.

Comment: *"It sounds like.."*  Does it 'sound like' they do not ever want a border on that component, or a definite (as opposed to chance) BG fill?  It's best not to presume these things..

Comment: Working code is updated please take a look again Thanks

Comment: @AndrewThompson `paintComponent` isn't responsible for painting borders, although I concede your point about the background.

Comment: @AdnanAli My answer is the same: Add the things you want to draw to a list so that your `paintComponent` method can repaint them all whenever the component needs to be repainted.

Comment: shapes.clear will aslo clear the points behind the lines ? or just lines?  Like clearRect() just remove lines not points

Comment: @AdnanAli It will empty the list of shapes that are to be drawn on screen, and thus clear the screen. I'm rather puzzled by what you're actually trying to achieve here. Do you ever want more than one triangle on the screen at once? Or do you just want one triangle that you move around?

Comment: @Boann You are not responsible for painting the child components or border, best practice is to override `paintComponent`.  If the OP wants to customise the way borders are painted then they should implement a `Border` and apply it.

Answer (score 2):

Your `mouseClicked` method should not create a new *Triangle* object. After resetting `triangle` just add new points to it. Also don't draw in this method but call `repaint`:

```
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        if (triangle.contains(p)) {
            System.out.println("1");
            triangle.reset();            // change the current triangle
            triangle.addPoint(600, 550); // new left
            triangle.addPoint(700, 350); // new top
            triangle.addPoint(800, 550); // new right
            repaint();                   // force repainting
        } else {
            System.out.println("Triangle dont have point");
        }
    }
```

Now if you want many triangles you should have a collection of `Polygon`s. Like this :

```
public static class TrianglePanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
    private Vector<Polygon> triangles;

    public TrianglePanel() {
        n = 0;
        // Create an empty collection
        triangles = new Vector<Polygon>();

        //Create first triangle
        Polygon triangle = new Polygon();
        triangle.addPoint(400, 550); //left   
        triangle.addPoint(600, 550); //right
        triangle.addPoint(500, 350); //top

        // Add the triangle to the collection
        triangles.add(triangle);

        //Add mouse Listener
        addMouseListener(this);

        //Set size to make sure that the whole triangle is shown
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    }

    /**
     * Draws the triangles as this frame's painting
     */
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        for (Polygon p : triangles) // Draw all triangles in the collection
            g2d.draw(p);
    }

    //Required methods for MouseListener, though the only one you care about is click
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

    /**
     * Called whenever the mouse clicks. Could be replaced with setting the
     * value of a JLabel, etc.
     */
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) this.getGraphics();
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        // Do what you want with p and the collection
        // For example : remove all triangles that contain the point p
        ListIterator<Polygon> li = triangles.listIterator();
        while (li.hasNext()) {
            if (li.next().contains℗) li.remove();
        }
        // Do what you want to update the list
        // For example: Add a new triangle...
        Polygon triangle = new Polygon();
        triangle.addPoint(600+n, 550);  // left
        triangle.addPoint(700+n, 350);  //top
        triangle.addPoint(800+n, 550);  //right
        triangles.add(triangle); // add the new triangle to the list
        n += 10; // next new triangle will be "moved" right
        repaint();
    }
    private int n;
}
```

Comment: This might be true for 1 to 1 triangle. but what if have to do 1 to many ? 1 remove and draw 3 ?

Comment: i Tried the code. when minimized and then un-minimize the screen. Triangle disappeared.. It means it have same problem as i was facing before.