# How to Re Draw Form in JForm.

Tags: java, graphics, awt, paint, repaint

I want to re-draw my screen (JForm) on button click. Due to some logic its not possible to do with repaint. Is there any other way to do so ?

When i Will click Save Pattern button. Shape should be redrawn.

If any one want to know why i cant do with paint the see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717816/what-is-alternative-of-paint-and-repaint-function)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Painting is done by overriding one of the paint methods of a component (preferably a component that extends from `JComponent` and by overriding `paintComponent`).

One possible solution is to render output to a `BufferedImage`, which allows you to do offscreen rendering and which you can control and when you want to, simply use `Graphics#drawImage` or even `JLabel` to render the `BufferedImage` to the screen